# how to release the bmp control that is taken by a graphic object in c#?

Tags: c#, graphics

i have this code

```
Bitmap bmp1, bmp2, bmp3,bmp4;

        Graphics gp2,gp3;



if (bmp2 == null)
                {
                    bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Height, pictureBox1.Width); 
                }
                    gp2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2);

                   // Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((float)(pictureBox1.Width / 2),(float)(pictureBox1.Height / 2),width, height);
                    gp2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp1,0,0);
                    gp2.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (float)(pictureBox1.Width / 2), (float)(pictureBox1.Height / 2), width, height);


                    gp2.Dispose();
```

but i am unable to release the control of gp2 as i want to give its control to gp3;

help required???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you should just be able to dispose of the `Graphics` and then call `Graphics.FromImage` again. I don't believe disposing of the `Graphics` will dispose of the underlying `Bitmap`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @moon: What exception? Is it reproducible? Can you provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: it throws exception here in  Application.Run(new Form1()); that is Object is currently in use elsewhere.

Comment: @moon: No more stack trace than that? Hmm... as before, a short but complete program would really help here...